# Solve the second-order ordinary differential equation $4y''+\frac1{y^3}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$4y''+\frac1{y^3}=0$$

I managed to turn this into a first order equation by multiplying by $y'$, then integrating by $x$:

$4y''y'+y'\frac1{y^3}=0\\2y'+\frac{-1}{2y^2}=E$

but when I tried to simplify, I encountered an unfamiliar expression:

$y'={2Ey^2+1\over4y^2}\\{dy\over dx}{4y^2\over Ey^2+1}=1\\\int{4y^2\over Ey^2+1}dy=\int1dx$

How can I integrate this expression by y? Is there anything I could've done differently to solve the equation?

Comment: $\displaystyle \int \frac{y^2}{y^2 + 1/E} \ \mathrm{d}y = \int \left(1 -  \frac{1/E}{y^2 + 1/E}\right) \ \mathrm{d}y = y - \frac{1}{\sqrt{E}}\arctan(y\sqrt{E})$

Comment: $2y’{}^2$, you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of your first integration contains an error; it should be (after multiplying by a constant)
$$4 (y')^\color{red}{2} - \frac{1}{y^2} = A .$$

Multiplying through by $y^2$ and rewriting in terms of $u := y^2$ gives a simpler equation,
$$(u')^2 - A u = 1 .$$

> One can use a general quadratic ansatz for $u$, giving the solutions $$u(x) = \frac{A (x + B)^2}{4} - \frac1A, \quad A \neq0, \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad u(x) = \pm x + B$$ for the equation in $u$.